# JavaFX - opening multiple windows on application startup

Tags: java, javafx, window

There are a couple questions on how to open a new window on pressing a button, but I'd like to open two windows when the application is launched.

My current approach is to put the following code in a new class that functions as the controller of the new window:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("secondWindow.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            parent = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            scene = new Scene(parent, 500, 400);
            stage = new Stage(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This works great for buttons or event based openings of windows, **I am looking for a simultaneous launching of the two windows**. Therefore I'd like to **launch my second window from the class with the main method.**

In this class you can find the first window being launched using this code:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

Right below I'd like to add code to launch the second window. I tried:

```
Parent secondRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("secondWindow.fxml"));
        Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondRoot);
        Stage secondStage = new Stage();
        secondStage.setScene(secondScene);
        secondStage.show();
```

which to my understanding should do it, but it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: monopolybank.SecondWindowController.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
```

**How can I fix my approach or what are alternatives to get the same result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is nothing to do with the number of windows and all to do with a constructor with parameters that you added to the monopolybank.SecondWindowController class that you created => remove the constructor from that class.